# Plugin directory page of my WP plugin doesn't reflect my recent svn commit

Tags: svn, plugins, wordpress, repository

I have committed a new version **1.5** of my [Image Metadata Cruncher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-metadata-cruncher/) plugin to the WP plugins repository, but the [plugin page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-metadata-cruncher/) of the WP Plugin Directory is after several days still showing the version **1.4**.

- The stable tag **1.5** is correct in both the [README.txt](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/image-metadata-cruncher/trunk/README.txt) as well as the [main PHP file](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/image-metadata-cruncher/trunk/image-metadata-cruncher.php) of the [trunk](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/image-metadata-cruncher/trunk/)
- There is a [1.5 tag](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/image-metadata-cruncher/tags/1.5/) in the [repository](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/image-metadata-cruncher/) which is a copy of the trunk

I have heard that the repository is checked every 15 minutes for new versions. I even experienced that sometimes it took hours that the new version was digested. But this time it lasts several days.

Is it a Wordpress's trac issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried asking for help on [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/hacks)? Might also be worth a try just barely modifying the readme.txt file in both the trunk and the tag, and committing that; I find that affects the front end very quickly (e.g. when I just want to bump "Tested up to")

Comment: The slight modification of the readme.txt did the job. Thanks